# Why 32bit JRE is needed to run certain applets when 64bit JRE is already installed

Tags: java, applet, java-8

Let me provide an example, Juniper's Network connect is a Java applet. This applet doesn't run from a ubuntu 64 bit OS with 64bit Java (JDK or JRE). To run this, their [support site](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25230)
suggest to install 32 bit JRE.

Additional info:
[Verify Java applet](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp) - successfully verifies that the browser is able to run Java applets.
Browser is 64 bit (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 )

I am unable to understand the fundamental need for a 32 bit JRE when 64 bit JRE is already available ? Can some one explain this. This will help many.

Comment: Probably because the browsers are 32bit and it may not be possible for 32bit apps to run 64 bit code...

Comment: Browser is 64bit. Other java applets runs successfully. Updated my question with these details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows- and *ix-systems there is no way to make a call from a 32-bit-executable to a 64-bit dynamic library (.dll or .so). So there's two possibilities one might need to use a 32-bit-jdk:

1. The application is getting called from a native 32-bit-aplpication like a 32-bit-browser
2. The java-application contains JNI-calls to native libraries that are only delivered as a 32-bit-version.

With an applet 1. is the most likely reason - but from your edit it seems more like 2. in your case.